# do the data aggregation with min value of other field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table like this in MySQL database.

```
Name Age code
foo  24  23
bar  23  21
mit  19  23
```

and I am doing data aggregation on the basis of `"code"` attribute, for that I am using `"group by"` in mysql like this

```
Select * from table group by code
```

output

```
foo 24 23
bar 23 21
```

I am only interested in aggregated result with min age.

Expected output is

```
mit 19 23
bar 23 21
```

I am looking for most optimized query for that.

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You want the row that has the minimum age for each code.  That means that there is no smaller age for the code. Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.code = t.code and t2.age < t.age);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the min age for each code using

```
SELECT code, MIN(age) FROM table GROUP BY code
```

If you want the `name` that corresponds to the min `age` per `code`, then it gets trickier unfortunately. This will work:

```
SELECT code, age, name 
FROM table JOIN (SELECT code, MIN(age) age FROM table GROUP BY code) t     
USING (code, age)
```

If you provide the indices on the table there is some optimization that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e0e9/3

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
ON t.code = t2.code
  AND t.age>t2.age
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```